# BUILD with @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser and SERVE with @angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, libraries, angular-devkit

I have an angular workspace with this structure:

```
├── projects
│    ├── lib-1
│    ├── lib-2
│    ├── lib-wrapper
│    .
│    .
│
└── src
     ├── app
     ├── assets
     .
     .
```

where I develop my libraries and test it directly on my app (src). In particular `lib-wrapper` imports `lib-1` and `lib-2` and then app imports `lib-wrapper`.
Until today, to test "runtime" the libraries adn to have live reloading for each change of a lib, I have to import lib-wrapper and lib-1/2 with the ugly import form `import {x} from ../../../lib-1/src/public-api.ts` or something like that. When I have to build the libraries and the application I have to change all imports in "installed version" like `import {x} from lib-1` (the same for lib-wrapper).

Did someone knows the correct configuration of `tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.app.json` and `angular.json` in section `architect.build.builder` and `architect.serve.builder` to import libraries always with form `import {x} from lib-1` and to use direct import to have live reloading when I serve my app, and to use installed libraries when I build the app?

Note: my angular version is
Angular CLI: 14.2.5
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| @angular-devkit/architect | 0.1402.5 |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular | 14.2.5 |
| @angular-devkit/core | 12.2.18 |
| @angular-devkit/schematics | 12.2.18 |
| @angular/cdk | 14.2.4 |
| @angular/flex-layout | 10.0.0-beta.32 |
| @angular/material | 14.2.4 |
| @angular/material-moment-adapter | 14.2.4 |
| @schematics/angular | 12.2.18 |
| ng-packagr | 14.2.1 |
| rxjs | 6.6.7 |
| typescript | 4.6.4 |